# jquery to count chracters and add class not working

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have some javascript that i found on here but I cannot seem to get it to work.

I have a h1 with the id 'latest' which should have the class pt45 if there is less than 21 characters.

```js
// The number of characters
    var yourElement = $('h1.latest');
    var charLength = yourElement.text().length;
    if(charLength < 20){
       yourElement.addClass('pt45');
    }
```

```css
.pt45 {
    font-size: 10px;
    color:red;
}
```

```html
<h1 class="latest">123456789</h1>
<h1 class="latest">123456789123456789123456789123456789</h1>
```

Comment: it's not `h1` with `id`, it's `class`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
  var yourElement = $('h1.latest');
```

This will return you a jQuery Object containing matching NodeList.

`yourElement.text().length;` will give two as you have two h1

Instead it must be:

```js
 jQuery("h1.latest").each(function() {
    if(jQuery(this).text().length < 21 ) {
       jQuery(this).addClass("pt45")
    }
 });
```

```css
.pt45 {
    font-size: 10px;
    color:red;
}
```

```html
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>


<h1 class="latest">123456789</h1>
<h1 class="latest">123456789123456789123456789123456789</h1>
```

You must iterate the Nodelist and check for the length

Comment: False. It will return a `jQuery` collection. `document.querySelectorAll('h1.latest')` will return a `NodeList`.

Comment: Oh ya.. It's a jQuery object containing the matching nodelist elements

Comment: I see it working on the run code snippet hwoever when adding to the site it doesn't work. Here is a link to the site: http://alturl.com/ria2w it is the latest news section, 3 boxes. you will see 1 has a single line of text and two have double lines for the header. I am trying to affect the shorter single line.

Comment: You've used `id="latest"` instead of "class="latest". Id must be unique in a page. refer the classes

Comment: You've used `id="latest"` instead of "class="latest"

Comment: I have removed the id and now only have the class latest. still not working?

Comment: In your code, $ is not jQuery. So i've updated answer. Please use with jQuery

Comment: Thank you, I have updated the code on the website. Still nothing :S

Comment: Great. Wrap the code inside `jQuery(function() { // code here })`

Answer (score 0):

`$('h1.latest')` the object selects all the h1 element with have class `latest`. Use `$(this)` for current object select and itreate in each loop

```
$('h1.latest').each(function() {
    if($(this).text().length < 20){
        $(this).addClass('pt45')
    }
});
```

[**Fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/dxbezrya/2/)

Answer (score 0):

As per jquery documentation you can see that the `.addClasss()` method can take a function as a callback and you can return the values from it. so instead of taking a loop on each `h1.latest` you just return the class to be added.

Try this:

```js
$('h1.latest').addClass(function() {
   return this.textContent.length < 20 ? "pt45" : "";
});
```

```css
.pt45 {
  font-size: 10px;
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h1 class="latest">123456789</h1>
<h1 class="latest">123456789123456789123456789123456789</h1>
```